# Change IMAP folder size limits using API

Tags: email, imap, gmail-api

On your [gmail account settings](https://mail.google.com/mail/#settings/fwdandpop) you can set IMAP folder size limit:
[image: GMAIL IMAP folder size limits]

My goal is to select "Do not limit the number of messages in an IMAP folder (default)" option using some kind of API, but there is nothing useful in [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/?csw=1#manage_imap_settings).
Is there any other way to turn off this limit?

Comment: Probably not. This is so a user can customize their imap experience by constraining an imap client, not for a client to override. It'd defeat the point a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Gmail API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/) to do this.  Calling the users.settings.updateImap method with `maxFolderSize` set to `0` will remove the folder limit.  Reference doc: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/settings/updateImap

Comment: Wow, that's handy! Thanks!